# Why i can't install native-base with npm in my react-native project?

Tags: react-native, npm, installation, native-base

```sh
npm install native-base --save
```

I've this error:

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ENETUNREACH: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 104.16.22.35:443
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! path /Users/.../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! code EISGIT

npm ERR! git /Users/.../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /Users/.../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.../.npm/_logs/2019-05-14T10_13_00_776Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue usually happens sometimes, as a temporary fix, follow these steps:

1. delete the this folder in the node_modules directory

   ```
   C:\Users\...\node_modules\react-native-safe
       -area-view
   ```
2. Install the package you are trying to add again.

   ```
   npm install native-base --save
   ```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: i don't have this folder in my node_module. im still getting this error